# Recurring "OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" with JBOSS EJB CLIENT

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jboss

This error happens a lot when calling an EJB service on JBOSS EAP 6.4 and it always happens on EJBClientContext registerEJBReceiver / unregisterEJBReceiver. These methods both submit a runnable into a CachedThreadPool (Executors.newCachedThreadPool) named ejbClientContextTasksExecutorService.
The code can be viewed inside the class EJBClientContext:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wildfly/jboss-ejb-client/87aef56ab787f57a9508c6e2b0f876066ae464fe/src/main/java/org/jboss/ejb/client/EJBClientContext.java

I have a JBOSS Client application which is a batch that creates fixed number of 20 threads (with Executors.newCachedThreadPool) but each task invokes an EJB remote object that uses the CachedThreadPool of EJBClientContext.

The number of threads that are running inside the CachedThreadPool of EJBClientContext is unknown but I checked some OS limits that appear to be more than enough :

nproc > 100000

ulimit -u > 100000

kernel.pid_max > 100000

/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max > 150000

I have been watching thread consumption on the server during the whole duration of the batch with the following command:

```
ps -A -o pid,nlwp,cmd
```

The number of threads per process remains quite low (maximum 100 threads per process, for 2 or 3 processes at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Try to profile your application. If you are using Oracle JDK you can create a [flight recording](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH170) an analyse it with [JMC](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/index.html). Then you have a good analyse over time until the error occurs.

Also found a good [article](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshoot-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new). Try to compare the results from the analyse with it.